# Complete metric space, not simply-connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I've been going over the algebraic topology part of Munkres and this question has stumped me. If we have a complete metric space that is not compact, must it be simply-connected (path-connected plus trivial fundamental group)? My intuition tells me no, but I can't come up with an example.

Comment: infinite cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ but $z$ unrestricted in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: A closed subset of a complete metric space is complete. Start with $\mathbb R^n$ and build your favorite counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

Even worse: a complete metric space doesn't have to be connected. One example is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counterexample is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an open disc removed.

You can also construct counterexamples by taking any old non-simply connected space (such as a circle) and gluing it to any old non-compact space (such as the real line) at a single point, provided both spaces are complete.

Answer (score 0):

Zillions of examples: start with any compact Riemannian manifold $M$ and any nontrivial infinite index subgroup $G < \pi_1 M$, then apply covering space theory to get an infinite degree covering map $p : N \mapsto M$ such that the image of the induced monomorphism $p_* : \pi_1(N) \to \pi_1(M)$ is $G$. The Riemannian manifold $N$ is complete, has fundamental group isomorphic to $G$, and is not compact.